# Bootstrap Carousel Indicators Color change for 1 slide

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am using the default bootstrap carousel. But one of my slides has a white background so the carousel indicators disappear on that slide. I have Javascript/jQuery solution that works, but it seems a tiny bit slow/clunky. Any help either to improve the script or an alternative solution, would be appreciated.

```
$('#carousel-generic').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (evt) {
    var elem = $(this).find('.carousel-indicators li'); 
    var active = $(this).find('.carousel-indicators .active');
    if(active.index() == 2) {
        elem.css('border-color', 'grey');
        elem.css('background-color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');
        active.css('background-color', 'grey');
    } else {
        elem.css('border-color', 'white');
        elem.css('background-color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');
        active.css('background-color', 'white');
    }
})
```

Comment: If this code is working and you're asking how to improve it, you should post this question on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 6):

Since you already know which one you need to change (hence your `index()`), then just create CSS styles for it

```
.carousel .carousel-indicators li {
    // normal styles
}
.carousel .carousel-indicators li.active {
    // active styles
}
.carousel .carousel-indicators li:nth-of-type(3).active {
    // index() is 0 based index, and nth-of-type starts at 1
    // special styles for that one instance
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I would prefer a css solution. But I don't think there is a css solution. My css is not great. But as I see it now a an additional class needs to be added to the parent .carousel-indicator , when its child the 2nd li becomes active. I don't think it can be done in css. That said, the script solution isn't to bad. I think I will keep it. and close this question. Thanks for your time Rob.

Comment: @blurb - this is a CSS solution. You don't have to add a class just use `nth-of-type` selector

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution

```
.carousel-indicators li {
    background-color: #669966;
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
    background-color: #FF7600;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `background-color:"color"` to `.carousel`, `.carousel-indicators li`,
that may work fine.